# Why does the rule "grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax())" not work?

Tags: html, css, grid

My parent flex element has several child elements (flex and grid mixed). I can't use `auto-fit` and `minmax()` properties in the `grid-template-columns` rule in the child grid element.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(9em, 100%), 1fr));
```

**Expected behavior:**

1. The menu items should line up.
2. And the width of each menu item should be the same regardless of the length of the character text.
3. The width of the menu items should dynamically change depending on the number of menu items.
4. The menu items should fill all the free space on the line and only when there is not enough free space on the line, they should be moved to a new line to keep the grid flat.

**Actual behavior:**

1. The menu items do not fill the free space in the line and are moved to a new line, despite the fact that their width allows them to line up.
2. As a result, instead of items lined up in a line with dynamic width, we get menu items lined up in a column with minimal width.

My work project is written in React and has many nested components, so citing code here is difficult. Instead, I wrote a small header in html + css, similar to what I have in my working project.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1.5px solid #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
}

/* parent flex element */
.wrapper {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  /* Maybe it's because the parent element is flex and the child is grid, but that would be strange... */
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: space-between; /* This rule does not affect "auto-fit" */
  align-items: center; 
  
}

.logo {
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

/* children grid element (auto-fit not working) */
.menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,        minmax(min(9em, 100%), 1fr));  /* WORKING */ 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr );  /* WORKING */ 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(9em, 1fr));  /* auto-fit + minmax = NOT WORKING !!! */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(9em, 100%), 1fr));  /* auto-fit + minmax = NOT WORKING !!! */
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 0px 1.5ch;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: .035em;
  transition: all ease-in-out 150ms;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #30ba8f;
}

.change-theme-buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.change-theme-buttons > button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 150ms;
}

.change-theme-buttons > button:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.2em;
} 

.change-theme-buttons :nth-child(1) {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-right: 0px;
}

.change-theme-buttons :nth-child(2) {
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.change-theme-buttons :nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 0px;
}

.search {
  position: relative;
}

.search-input {
  height: 32px;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1.5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.search-input::placeholder {
  color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1.5px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.search-svg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <wrapper class="wrapper"> <!-- parent flex element -->
    
    <button class="logo">L</button>
        
    <menu class="menu"> <!-- children grid element (auto-fit not working)-->
      <button class="menu-item">About</button>
      <button class="menu-item">Technology</button>
      <button class="menu-item">Blog</button>
    </menu>
    
    <div class="change-theme-buttons">
      <button>D</button>
      <button>L</button>
      <button>S</button>
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      <input class="search-input" type="search" />
      <svg class="search-svg"></svg>
    </div>
  </wrapper>
</header>
```

Also a link to **[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/georgiigalechyan/pen/GRByVYe)**.

The problem seems to be with elements in the `wrapper` and `menu` classes. I added some comments in the CSS that may be helpful. Ideally, any solution would keep the original idea of using `auto-fit` and `minmax()` (if it's possible).

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", you need to explain what you expect to happen versus what actually happens.

Comment: @BrettDonald Hello. Thank you for the comment. I have made corrections to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(9em, 1fr));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, though it should! That's what's so strange. We're missing something.)

Look at CSS on codepen.io (there is a link in the question itself). There are options for what works and what doesn't. It's the combination of "auto-fit" and "minmax" that is failing.

Comment: To add more, here is the best article: https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain to us why you want to use `auto-fit` and `minmax()`. Your header looks pretty good with just `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1.5px solid #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center; 
  
}

.logo {
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
/*
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(min(9em, 100%), 1fr));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr );
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(9em, 1fr));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(9em, 100%), 1fr));
*/
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 0px 1.5ch;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: .035em;
  transition: all ease-in-out 150ms;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #30ba8f;
}

.change-theme-buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.change-theme-buttons > button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 150ms;
}

.change-theme-buttons > button:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.2em;
} 

.change-theme-buttons :nth-child(1) {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-right: 0px;
}

.change-theme-buttons :nth-child(2) {
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.change-theme-buttons :nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 0px;
}

.search {
  position: relative;
}

.search-input {
  height: 32px;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1.5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.search-input::placeholder {
  color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1.5px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.search-svg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <wrapper class="wrapper"> <!-- parent flex element -->
    
    <button class="logo">L</button>
        
    <menu class="menu"> <!-- children grid element (auto-fit not working)-->
      <button class="menu-item">About</button>
      <button class="menu-item">Technology</button>
      <button class="menu-item">Blog</button>
    </menu>
    
    <div class="change-theme-buttons">
      <button>D</button>
      <button>L</button>
      <button>S</button>
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      <input class="search-input" type="search" />
      <svg class="search-svg"></svg>
    </div>
  </wrapper>
</header>
```

Comment: Hello. The "auto-fit" property is used when you don't know the exact number of elements in a string. Right now I have three elements in the menu, but in the future this number may change up or down. The "minmax" property allows menu items to change their width and adjust to the number of items. The width of the menu items should be the same regardless of the length of the text.